# How to authorize user and admin in Laravel using jwt?

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt

My action:
1) I installed jwt-auth
2) Created the controller AuthController
3) in a route I send in methods loginUser and loginAdmin in AuthController

But jwt-auth tries to authorize through the User model.

My method auth admin:

```
public function adminLogin(Request $request){
    Config::set('jwt.user', 'App\Admins');
    Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Admins::class);
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $token = null;
    try {
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'response' => 'error',
                'message' => 'invalid_email_or_password',
            ]);
        }
    } catch (JWTAuthException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'response' => 'error',
            'message' => 'failed_to_create_token',
        ]);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'response' => 'success',
        'result' => [
            'token' => $token,
            'message' => 'I am Admin user',
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Returns the config with the App\Admins
but JWT: Auth refers to the user model, how to fix it?

My composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0-rc.2"
},
```

> decision:
>   [guard plugun](https://github.com/paulvl/jwt-guard) install my project

My method code:

```
 public function adminLogin(Request $request){
    Config::set('jwt.user', 'App\Admins');
    Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Admins::class);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $token = null;
    try {
        if (!$token = Auth::guard('jwt')->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'response' => 'error',
                'message' => 'invalid_email_or_password',
            ]);
        }
    } catch (JWTAuthException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'response' => 'error',
            'message' => 'failed_to_create_token',
        ]);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'response' => 'success',
        'result' => [
            'token' => $token,
            'message' => 'I am Admin user',
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Not the best solution, but it works and shares users and admins.

Comment: instead of setting the config during runtime, could you modify the files? there is a non zero chance that the config is read before you try to modify it

Comment: @Quezler Why is the default parameter "default" from auth.php
I tried to change to the provider admin, he switched to the Admin model, but the issue of the token for the User stopped working

Comment: I mean you are setting `Config::set('jwt.user', 'App\Admins');` and `Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Admins::class);` during runtime instead of the config files in the `config` directory

Comment: Yes, I install these configs in the method of the controller. There is also a similar method, only for user authorization